# Using SignalR with ASP.NET MVC 5.2 to send a message when a long-running operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'd like to use SignalR with ASP.NET MVC 5.2 because I think it's the right choice for my needs :

A user can start a long running operation (identified by a unique ID) from a web portal. When the operation is completed, I want to update the status on the web portal (using SignalR in this case).

The long-running job itself is not performed by the ASP.NET MVC code. It's in a completely different system, however, I can do whatever I want at the end of the operation (call a URL, update a DB, ...).

I thought of two solutions :

**Writing the status in a DB when the operation completes. Monitoring the DB in my ASP.NET MVC code, and sending SignalR message when I detect the correct state in the DB**

I think this is not a good solution because I don't think it's a best practice to create that kind of "monitoring background thread" directly in the web portal, IIS can stop the pool if there are no web requests, etc...

**Calling a specific URL at the end of the long running operation**

When the client starts the operation from the web page, I add it in a [SignalR Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-3.1#groups-in-signalr) named after the unique operation ID.

I create a specific `Action` on my ASP.NET MVC project, and call the corresponding URL (from the external system) when the operation finishes while providing the operation's unique ID to find the correct group. So, I can send the message to the wanted client using something like this:

```
var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
hub.Clients.Group(groupName).signalOperationCompleted();
```

In this case I'll need to properly protect this Action to prevent clients from sending fake completion messages.

What do you think about these solutions? Is there another one that would be recommended?

Comment: Does the user have to check the status himself by going to a specific "result URL," or does he have a dashboard that tells him this status in real-time?

Comment: Is there a possibility from you/your team to create a microservice responsible to push notifications to your mvc app?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't expect the user to navigate/refresh the page, the status should be in real-time

Comment: @Kiril1512 I'm not sure to understand, what would be the benefit of a microservice over an Action ?

Comment: You could do it for any other need to your application using SignalR to notify other events and other scenarios that you would need. This is just a recommendation, not an answer to your question.